# <div> class not getting displayed in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

i want to output data in table form from database using php.
& with alternate colors in the table

But it doesnt display alternate colors, the browser is making div tag before php code starts & so the colors doesnt display.

part of the code :

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM form1 ORDER by id   ");

    echo "<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>userName</th>
        <th>e-Mail id</th>";

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['id'] % 2 == 1) {

            echo '<div class = "odd">';
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class = "even">';
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }

    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: A `<div>` tag cannot be a direct child of `<table>`. Place your class on the `<tr>` instead of wrapping it in a `<div>`

Answer (score 3):

Just set the class to the TR

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM form1 ORDER by id   ");

echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>userName</th>
    <th>e-Mail id</th>
    </tr>";

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr class=\"".(($row['id'] % 2 == 1)?"odd":"even")."\">";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['mail'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Hey thank you buddy
But can you please explain to me what have you done ?
I am new to php so i just find ir difficult to understand the line you addded

Comment: Syntax error
unexpected :

Comment: @dharmil007 sorry a `:` slipped in after the `?` fixed the code. Sure you fixed it by now

Comment: Also here: http://davidwalsh.name/php-ternary-examples explaining the `?` and `:`

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM form1 ORDER by id   ");

echo "<table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>userName</th>
    <th>e-Mail id</th>
    </tr>";

$class = 'even';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $class = $class=='even' ? 'odd' : 'even';

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td class="' . $class . '">" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class="' . $class . '">" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class="' . $class . '">" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class="' . $class . '">" . $row['mail'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Might be best to finish off the header row `</tr>` and change the divs as per the comment on the main

Comment: @klors sorry, that was a mistake from the original post :)

Comment: Yeah, just helping you get a fuller answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you should not really put div tag outside of tr tag, better set class attribute to tr tag, like

```
<tr class="odd">
```